# creating contacts from remote websites

Tags: wordpress, contacts

is it possible to create new contacts using remote html forms?

we have three different websites related to different activities of the organization.

we would like to create adding contact forms on each of these websites and have the form perform data-entry to a single civicrm running on a separate wordpress installation.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: we have just installed civicrm for the first time, and would appreciate any help, even it may be obvious. cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. CiviCRM provides an "html snippet" for every profile form you create. Simply copy and paste this into your remote website and form submissions will be saved back to your CiviCRM database.

For more information see http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/#standalone-forms-with-profiles

Answer (score 4):

Speaking generally, yes, you can use CiviCRM's [REST API](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface) to do things remotely. In your case, that includes [creating contacts](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface#RESTinterface-CreateContact).

For further reference, see the wiki article on [Using the API](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Drupal and need more nuanced or complex forms then you can also use Webform-civicrm and embed in an iframe. Generally that requires having a drupal 'blank' theme so you just get the form and nothing else. So extra work, but provides extra benefits that webform-civicrm does so nicely.

Comment: Question says they are using WordPress, so not an option for this site.

Comment: ah yes in the tags. tweaked to make this a general answer for others who might be attracted by the title.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the [inlay](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/inlay) extension and [inlayfp](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/inlayfp). You can create forms using CiviCRM and embed in any website supporting a script tag.