# Can multiple websites be synchronized under the same CRM installation

Tags: wordpress, multisite, sync

I am very new to CiviCRM so I'm sorry if this sounds silly.
I want to ask if you can install the CRM on one website, but manage/gather/synchronize the activities from another one. As an idea, I will try it on Wordpress, but the question is generic.

For example, the main website is one of the main organization (which has various activities, products etc.), where Civi would be installed, then there is another one, like an online shop for example (with products mngmt., sales, marketing actions etc.) which needs to send its activities to the main website too.

Can that be achieved?
If yes, is it possible with just one Civi instance or there needs to be an instance on each wesite?
In any case, I'm really excited about this platform that I recently found out about and it seems absolutely amazing.

Thanks for any feedback.
Andy

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a single civicrm wired to several CMS instances.

There is some documentation here

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/

There are hurdles to get over, for example, how to synch users across the various CMS

There are other approaches to pull in data from other sites without wiring CiviCRM in to it including

- [Remote Forms](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform)
- [Profiles using HTML snippets](http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/#standalone-forms-with-profiles)
- using the [RestAPI](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/REST+interface)

Some good answers [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/creating-contacts-from-remote-websites)

Perhaps best if you want more input on this Q+A to add more info to your Question detailing a bit more including how you see logged in users functioning across the sites

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sounds promising and I will study the links you sent.
I am not very clear in what the workflow between websites should be but as an idea, there would be for example sales comming from both sites.
Maybe email marketing base that question is should it be managed on one website or have separate email lists for both? These kind of things and more...

In any case, I didn' even install it yet, so I'll try to find time do do it on a test website and then I'll come back with more feedback. :)
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: if you can see a route for doing this with a single website then i would probably do that and avoid the headaches